# Is there a way to listen to progress of CoreNLP processing with annotations?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I'm using CoreNLP 3.6.0 in Java desktop application in order to parse date values from documents

```
Properties props = new Properties();
PIPELINE.addAnnotator(new TokenizerAnnotator(false));
PIPELINE.addAnnotator(new WordsToSentencesAnnotator(false));
PIPELINE.addAnnotator(new POSTaggerAnnotator(false));
PIPELINE.addAnnotator(new TimeAnnotator("sutime", props));
Annotation annotation = new Annotation(input);
annotation.set(CoreAnnotations.DocDateAnnotation.class, "2013-07-14");
PIPELINE.annotate(annotation);
List<CoreMap> timexAnnsAll = annotation.get(TimeAnnotations.TimexAnnotations.class);
```

Is there any way I can listen to the progress of the recognition?

Answer (score 0):

Not currently, no. What's the use-case you have in mind? In principle this could be built (e.g., a callback before+after each annotator in a pipeline is run), but so far [as of March 2017] we haven't had a particular use-case for it.

Comment: I'm developing [document-scanner](https://github.com/document-scanner/document-scanner) which allows its user to define meta-data for a scanned document or opened PDF (sender, recipient, date, amount of bill, etc.) and I'm using the above code to propose date values to choose from based on the document text (from the PDF or after OCR). Since that takes long time the value detection is performed in a background thread and a GUI component should display the progress. The code above might be unsuitable for that. I'm about to figure out this amazing framework.